# How to display Icon in a .exe File in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, icons, exe

I am working on a Qt app where I need to display some UI and perform operation on them. When i run the application it creates a `.exe` in my debug/release folder. I want to put the icon in the `.exe` file rather than a blank icon which appears by default.

Is their a way one can do it in .ui file or we need to do it programmatically? I am kinda sure I need to use a resource file and store the image there. I tried to search for some more details but couldn't figure out anything related to `Qt`. Please help :)

Comment: If by `a .exe` you mean you create an executable file then you cannot 'put an icon inside'. At least not such that it is displayed in a file manager.

Comment: @arkascha: No No.... I am looking for a way where I can set the image of executable first and when I run the application, it should appear in debug/release folder :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that: what is 'the image of executable'? And what debug/release folder when you execute some program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds very interesting:

> I tried to search for some more details but couldn't figure out
>   anything related to Qt

The official manual, which is accidentally the first result on Google for "qt set application icon" search query, will help you:
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/appicon.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Greenfish](http://download.cnet.com/Greenfish-Icon-Editor-Pro/3000-2193_4-10773415.html) icon editor